# How to authenticate a twitter api request?

Tags: json, rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to make twitter api requests in my browser (I wan to look at the JSON before writing code to parse it in my android app) but every request is returning:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

So how do I properly authenticate the request?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [OAuth.io](https://OAuth.io) for a while to do proper authenticated requests: they specifically have a feature called Request API or something like that: check their [Documentation](https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/default/rest#request-api) this might help you I hope.